# How print(input() + input()) works in python ? Without variable assignment?

Tags: python, input, printing

```
a = input()
b = input()
print(a+b)
```

This can be written as 
`print(input()+input())` and it works.
How does it work? Where are the inputs are stored temporarily?

Comment: Well they're obviously stored in memory somewhere temporarily, but exactly how is just an implementation detail. The code asks for the sum (concatenation) of two values, each of which are retrieved through a call to `input` - so it has to store the values somewhere. But those values isn't accessible to your Python code if you write it in this shorthand way.

Comment: @RobinZigmond nevertheless, I'm interested where that "somewhere" is, actually :)

Comment: I guess it's no different than any other function being evaluated before being passed as an argument, it's just the inherent behaviour of `input` that makes it seem weird.

Comment: Where are the temporary results for `print((7+5)*(1+3))` stored and why does it matter to anyone? They are briefly on the stack.

Comment: @tripleee I really just think it's down to the way that `input()` works. When I first considered the question it seemed intriguing, but actually it's just the same as passing any other argument. I guess it's the pause in execution that elicits a "what's going on here?" response and makes it seem different :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Premise: `input()` is just a normal function that blocks until the user types something in. Once that is done, the data is evaluated and returned.

With that set aside, your statement is composed of several parts:

`print(...)` is a function call that prints the *result* of the *expression* that is between its parentheses.

The *expression* then is `input() + input()`. Since the `operator()` has a higher precedence than `operator+`, the two `input()` calls will be evaluated before the sum.

The *result* of an `input()` is an **unnamed temporary variable** that exists *only until the full expression is evaluated*. Once the `+` is executed, the temporary variables are effectively lost (and will be garbage collected eventually).

Comment: @Macow I don't know what CS background you have so I don't know if I was clear enough. "Statement", "expression" and "operator" are all specific terms in (basic) language theory and I'm using them assuming you know the difference. If that's not the case, let me know and I'll elaborate further

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that input itself is a function, hence the value is being stored as a process part of the function itself. The output is a simple return, hence why you can freely call the function without parameters, and it separates it, too.

```
def input(*kwargs):
    eval(raw_input(prompt))
```

Just because it doesn't look like a complex function doesn't mean it isn't.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input

Answer (score -3):

input() returns input value from prompt.

It is possible to do so by returning immediately rather than saving the temporary repository.

Comment: There should be a temporary repository as there are two inputs which are taken one after the other?