# Using the value of the input() method without using a variable Python

Tags: python-3.x, user-input

I'd like to print the value of the `input()` method when this value is a part of the list `myList`. I want to get the value of the `input()` and print it without using a variable

```
myList = ["Banana", "Apple", "Lemon","Strawberry"]

if input() in myList:
        print(input())
    else:
        print("Not found")
```

The line `print(input())` doesn't get the value of the input. And I want to get this value if it's in the `myList`

Comment: You can't. `input()` returns the inputted string. If you want to use it later, you have to keep it somewhere

Comment: You must use a variable,No alternative

Comment: Your first input() gets the input from the user and checks against the list. However you are calling input() method again and so this is a new instance of input and will NOT match the earlier input. If you want to reference the previous one, you have to store it into a variable and then check

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How print(input() + input()) works in python ? Without variable assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53723533/how-printinput-input-works-in-python-without-variable-assignment)

Comment: As explained in the link above `The result of an input() is an unnamed temporary variable that exists only until the full expression is evaluated. Once the + is executed, the temporary variables are effectively lost (and will be garbage collected eventually).` In your case, the moment your statement moves out of the if statement check, the temporary variable is effectively lost even if the code goes inside the if statement

Answer (score 0):

As explained in my comment earlier, please review how input statement works.

[How print(input() + input()) works in python ? Without variable assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53723533/how-printinput-input-works-in-python-without-variable-assignment)

This is an extract from the above link to another similar question:

- The result of an input() is an unnamed temporary variable that exists
  only until the full expression is evaluated. Once the + is executed,
  the temporary variables are effectively lost (and will be garbage
  collected eventually).

In essence, you cannot access the value in the input() statement unless you store it into a variable. As soon as your code gets outside the `if input() in mylist:`, the value is lost. If you want to access it, you need to store it and use it.

Can you please explain why you don't want to store the value into a variable?